# How to add upload button in order view section in magento?

Tags: magento, file-upload, view

I need a Upload field in order view section in magento under Sales->Orders->View->Information->Order Tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can add new table row containg file upload in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml` file